# Text Alignment in VBA PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there a way to align the text from right to left (it's Arabic) on all slides in a PowerPoint Presentation with a macro ? (I'm using O365).

In a Microsoft example I found this :

```
Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2) _
    .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
```

But i think that this example aligns the paragraphs of form 2 on slide 1 of the active presentation to the left.

So i don't know how to do it with all the shapes/slides types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The professional coders may improve it, but I think this one should help you. You just have to select all slides before you click it, if you want the entire presentation to be done in one move. I think it is better than any entire-presentation-solution, because it gives you the opportunity to choose.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AlignAllTextLeft()
 
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim notesshp As Shape
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim x As Long

    On Error GoTo ErMsg

    If MsgBox("You are going to change the text alignment of all text on all selected slides to left" & vbCrLf & "Continue?", vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
 
For Each osld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
 For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
 If oshp.HasTextFrame Then
 oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignLeft
 End If
 If oshp.HasTable Then
             For i = 1 To oshp.Table.Rows.Count
                For j = 1 To oshp.Table.Columns.Count
 oshp.Table.Rows.Item(i).Cells(j).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignLeft
                 Next j
            Next i
 End If
 Next oshp

 For Each notesshp In osld.NotesPage.Shapes
 If notesshp.HasTextFrame Then
 notesshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignLeft
 End If
 Next notesshp
 Next osld
 
For Each osld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
    For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
    
        With oshp
            Select Case .Type
                Case Is = msoGroup
                For x = 1 To .GroupItems.Count
                    If .GroupItems(x).HasTextFrame Then
                         oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignLeft
                    End If
                Next x
            End Select
        End With
    Next oshp
    Next

Exit Sub

ErMsg:
    MsgBox "Please do not place the cursor between two slides"

End Sub
```